# how do I make latex allow breaking a line whenever reaching line boundary

Tags: line-breaking, margins, amsmath

I started writing my HW in latex, I use an online latex editor+compiler. Sometimes, when I write long math expressions, the expressions exceed the right boundaries of the page.
I've seen that it has to do something with hyphenation package, but I couldn't find the right way to do it.

My zero order question would be how could I tell latex, that it can break a line at any character. It's not that nice, but HW doesn't have to be perfectly nice.

I noticed that latex knows how to break expressions with arithmetic signs such as + or \times. Is there a way which I can tell latex to be able to break a line, with some other specific characters?

I tried using \hyp and \discretionary but I get errors in the compilation. I think it was because I'm trying to use them inside math expression ($ ... $).

One more thing. My expressions are not that long on themselves, but it's the fact that I show the entire development of it. So actually, it's a series of long expressions separated by equal signs. To my surprise, latex did not break in the equal sign as well. I even broke the expressions apart $...=$ $...=$ $...=$ and it didn't break between them either

any help would be much appreciated

UPDATE
as an example

```
$\int d^3x (\partial_0 A^0)^2 = \int d^3x\int \hat{dk}\hat{dq} k_0q_0\left(-a^\lambda(k)\epsilon^\lambda_0(k)e^{-ikx}\right)\left(-a^{\lambda'}(q)\epsilon^{\lambda'}_0(q)e^{-iqx}\right) =  \int \hat{dk}\hat{dq} k_0q_0a^\lambda(k)\epsilon^\lambda_0(k)e^{-ik_0t}a^{\lambda'}(q)\epsilon^{\lambda'}_0(q)e^{-iq_0t} \int d^3xe^{-i(\vec{k}+\vec{q})x} = \int \hat{dk}\frac{d^3q}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{2|\vec{q}|}} k_0|\vec{q}|a^\lambda(k)\epsilon^\lambda_0(k)e^{-ik_0t}a^{\lambda'}(q)\epsilon^{\lambda'}_0(q)e^{-iq_0t}\delta^3(k+q)= \int \hat{dk}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{2|-\vec{k}|}} k_0|-\vec{k}|a^\lambda(k)\epsilon^\lambda_0(k)e^{-ik_0t}a^{\lambda'}(-k)\epsilon^{\lambda'}_0(-k)e^{-i|-\vec{k}|t}= \int \hat{dk}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3}\sqrt{2k_0}} (k_0)^2a^\lambda(k)a^{\lambda'}(-k)\epsilon^\lambda_0(k)\epsilon^{\lambda'}_0(-k)e^{-2ik_0t} $
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Would you mind showing a couple of inline equations that currently aren't being broken across lines?

Comment: Whether or not it breaks at an `=` sign, it should certainly break between equations: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{lipsum} \begin{document} \lipsum*[1] $a=b=c$ \end{document}` certainly does if I make insert enough equations.

Comment: latex will break at any  infix binary operator such as `+` or `-` and at any relation such as `=` but will not break inside `{}` groups. Perhaps you should be using `\raggedright` but in any case please always show a complete document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: thanks, but '=' surely didn't work. The \raggedright seemed to do the work. thanks